# Appending GoogleFinance while copy data from source sheet to target sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, google-finance

I am copying source sheet data to target sheet by using following code (Thanks to Iamblichus).

How to append the target sheet data with "=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,price)"  for all rows respectively.
I want to copy formula not value of the formula, so that I can get live value.

Column A of target sheet has stock codes.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Source");
const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Target");
const startRow = 2; 
const CHECK_COLUMN = 1; // Column A

function appendToRecords() {
  const numRows = sourceSheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Number of rows to process
  const numCols = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();
  const lastTargetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  const dataRange = sourceSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sourceSheet.getLastColumn()); // Fetch the range of cells being used
  const sourceData = dataRange.getValues(); // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  let targetData = [];
  // if (lastTargetRow > 1) targetData = targetSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastTargetRow-startRow+1, numCols).getValues();  // For heading in TSheet
  if (lastTargetRow > 0) targetData = targetSheet.getRange(1, 1, lastTargetRow, numCols).getValues();   // For no heading in Tsheet 
  const newData = sourceData.filter(sourceRow => {
    const columnA = sourceRow[CHECK_COLUMN-1];
    return !targetData.some(targetRow => targetRow[CHECK_COLUMN-1] === columnA);
  });
  if (newData.length) {
    targetSheet.getRange(lastTargetRow+1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what's your desired output. Do you mean the `Source` sheet has a series of stock codes in column A, and you want to write the formulas `=GOOGLEFINANCE(A1,price)` to a column in the target sheet? Also, where does `price` come from?

Comment: Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet so that the desired output is clarified.

Comment: Yes, Source sheet has the stocks codes.  where does price come from? Its a googlefinance syntax.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13NGHmUjnISK76wri8x9PoyU34KPLdW2TrOXVvoY5kuM/edit#gid=411614999  Sample spreadsheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where exactly you want to write the formulas, but, in case you want to add them to the first empty column (`I`), you can just use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to append the formula to each row:

```
  const newData = sourceData.filter(sourceRow => {
    const columnA = sourceRow[CHECK_COLUMN-1];
    return !targetData.some(targetRow => targetRow[CHECK_COLUMN-1] === columnA);
  }).map(row => row.concat(`=GOOGLEFINANCE("${row[0]}","price")`));
```

Comment: Done. Sorry for delay, as I was not aware of the option.